# How can I find a variable in a method body by type using mono.cecil?

Tags: c#, mono.cecil

I've had a look around the cecil questions here and I haven't seen anything regarding this particular question.

What I am trying to achieve is find a variable in `method.Body.Variables` that is of a certain type (`System.Exception` in my case)

I wrote the following code thinking it would do the trick:

```
var exceptionTypeReference = module.Import(typeof(Exception));
var exceptionVariable = method.Body.Variables.First(x => x.VariableType == exceptionTypeReference);
```

What seems strange to me even though I am sure the reason is my noobness with cecil is that I get a "Sequence contains no matching elements" error at runtime.

I've stepped through the code and I know there is a variable there and that it's type is `System.Exception`, but it does not want to match up with `exceptionTypeReference`.

I'm certain that this is simple and that my brain is fried from learning cecil. Even so, any pointers, smacks across the face with a wet fish, etc., would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each time you import a type it is a different instance of `TypeReference`

So this

```
var typeReference1 = moduleDefinition.Import(typeof (Exception));
var typeReference2 = moduleDefinition.Import(typeof (Exception));
Debug.WriteLine(typeReference1 == typeReference2);
```

Will output `false`.

So when you are doing the query

- `VariableType` may be an instance of `TypeReference` representing `Exception`
- `exceptionTypeReference` will be an instance of `TypeReference` representing `Exception`

But they are not the same reference and there is no built in equality checking on `TypeReference`.

What you need to do is

```
var exceptionType = module.Import(typeof(Exception));
var exceptionVariable = method
              .Body
              .Variables
              .First(x => x.VariableType.FullName == exceptionType.FullName);
```

Also remember you have to handle inherited exception types.

As a side not be careful using `.Import(typeof (Exception))`. The reason is that it give you the Exception type of the current code, not the Exception type of the target assembly. For example you could be processing a WinRT assembly using a .net4 assembly. Importing the .net4 Exception type will probably give you some strange behavior.

So you are just as safe doing this

```
var exceptionVariable = method
                   .Body
                   .Variables
                   .First(x => x.VariableType.FullName == "System.Exception");
```

Comment: Thank you @Simon. I did think of using the `FullName` property, but (foolishly) thought there would be a better way... I will use that instead. I was not aware of the Exception behaviour you described. Would you have some reading material on that (for research purposes)?